# How to show a custom modal popup on page reload in angular?

Tags: angular, angularjs

When user hits on refresh button on browser, a custom popup should be open for confirmation, With `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])` will be able to track the event, but unable to replace JavaScript alert box

Answer (score 2):

Try returning false in the handler, i made an example for you:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/beforeunload-tmbwzc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)